# Javascript bad practice to save reference of object or function as a variable for anonymous function

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous

I am developing code for a Facebook app for a website.  I am setting it up so others can use the JavaScript I write on other pages (even if they don't know much JS -- they can mirror my examples); sort of framework-ish.

Some pages we want to check if the user is logged into Facebook on page load, other times we don't.  So, inside the `ini` function I check to see if the `onPgLoadCheckLogin` value is set to true, then I use the Facebook toolkit to check that.

These functions work asynchronously and use callbacks to handle the responses.  I want to use functions that I have set up in the (no-so-much-of-a)framework.

To do this, because its a callback, I am saving a reference to the object/function in a variable called `me` - just before I execute the async stuff and set up the callback.

Is this bad practice?  If so, how can I get the callback to invoke the method I want to use?

Here is the code:

```
// Strict mode
"use strict";


/* Main object
 * @param config: array of app configuration
 */
var SMFbApp = function(config) {

    // app configuration
    this._config = (!!config && (typeof config).toLowerCase() == 'object') ? config : undefined;
    // check log in on page load
    this._onPgLoadCheckLogin = false;

    /*
     * ini
     * Initialize app
     */
    this.ini = function() {
        if(!this._config || (typeof this._config).toLowerCase() == 'undefined') {
            this._config = this.getDefaultConfig();
        }


        // mandatory configuration elements we need to address
        var fbini = [
            'appId', // dev facebook app id as default
            'cookie', // allow checking browser cookies
            'xfbml', // facebook markup in html doc ( example: <fb:login-button></fb:login-button> )
            'version', // sdk version
        ];

        var tmp = {}; // temp object to hold config vars
        // iterate through mandatory config and fill temp vars to init fbook sdk/api
        for(var idx in fbini) {
            if(!(fbini[idx] in this._config)) {
                console.error('Invalid configuration set passed to ShoeMoney Facebook App. Please review documentation for all necessary configuration values');
                this.exit(1);
            } else {
                tmp[fbini[idx]] = this._config[fbini[idx]];
            }
        }

        var me = this;
        // set up fb asycn init function with tmp object we just set up
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init(tmp);
            if(me._onPgLoadCheckLogin) {
                var _this = me;
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    _this.statChange(response);
                });
            }
        };


    }
```

And the part I am questioning as bad practice is (i do it twice):

```
var me = this; // HERE!!! once
// set up fb asycn init function with tmp object we just set up
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init(tmp);
    if(me._onPgLoadCheckLogin) {
        var _this = me; // HERE!! twice
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            _this.statChange(response);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not just get rid of the `var _this = me;` line and just use `me.statChange(response)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing with `var me = this;` is a perfectly fine practice and is a common way of saving the `this` value for a local callback function to access.  Though in your specific example, you don't have to create the `_this` variable.  You can just access `me` from both callbacks like this:

```
// save our object reference for later use in callbacks
var me = this; 
// set up fb asycn init function with tmp object we just set up
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init(tmp);
    if(me._onPgLoadCheckLogin) {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            me.statChange(response);
        });
    }
};
```

---

The other main alternative if the callbacks themselves don't use a `this` value that you need to access is to use `.bind()`, but in your specific example, you would have to use `.bind()` in two places to get both nested logins so your method of saving in `me` is probably simpler.

Here's what the `.bind()` alternative would look like:

```
// set up fb asycn init function with tmp object we just set up
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init(tmp);
    if(this._onPgLoadCheckLogin) {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            this.statChange(response);
        }.bind(this));
    }
}.bind(this);
```

For a reference, see [the MDN page for `.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: I ended up using the first method (removing the `_this` var).  Thank you!